# Batch findstr not reading file content?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch to extract the value of the `<Arguments>` element within each XML file in a subdirectory. Here is an example of the `<Arguments>` element within each file:

```
<Arguments>/Autostart /F:Hotel_Name_bkgs.mys /S:Server /P:"\\Abc-abc-01\g\Product Development\Share\All Connectors\Hotel Recaps\Hotel Chain\Booking_Recap_for_Hotel_Name_&amp;DATE&amp;.csv" /A:sender@example.com /E:receiver@example.com</Arguments>
```

Right now I just want to `echo` each value.

For some reason, it's not working. Where am I going wrong? `echo %%f` works, and if I put `start notepad %%f` in its place that works. But `echo %%i` is not working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R "%cd%\Legacy .xml files\" %%f in (*.xml) do (
    echo %%f
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<Arguments>" "%%f"') do (
        echo. %%i
    )
    echo.
)
pause
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue, even with a space in the filename of the XML file that's being read. Are you running the script as your regular user or as an Administrator? (I'm only asking because if you're running as Administrator, the script starts in C:\Windows instead of the directory where the script currently is, so it won't find the XML folder.)

Comment: @SomethingDark I am running it as a regular user.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your XML files are stored with some weird encoding. Make sure they're either ANSI or UTF-8; I'm able to reproduce your issue if I save the test data as UCS-2.

Comment: @SomethingDark Firefox says it's UTF-16LE. I used Notepad to overwrite using UTF-8 and it works. thanks!

Comment: If the encoding of the file is supported then all you should need is this short single line batch file: `@FindStr /ILS "<Arguments>" "Legacy .xml files\*.xml"`.